# Standard ML: Return different types

Tags: function, functional-programming, sml, ml

I need to return a different value based on the function passed into another function.

So, given:

```
fun inc x = x + 1;
```

And:

```
fun double([]) = [] 
  | double(h::t) = 2 * h :: double(t);
```

You should be able to call the function I'm working on with either.

Example call (the function I'm making is named test):

`test (inc, 5);` - And it would return **6**

-OR-

`test (double, [1,2,3,4]);` - And it would return **[2,4,6,8]**

I know that functions can't do this at face value, but is this possible through layers of abstraction?

Comment: *Even if there is* a way - if it's the answer, you are propably asking the wrong question. Why do you think you need it, and why can't you use `map` and singleton lists?

Comment: That's what I had meant when I said 'abstraction'. Using `map` was my first guess, I just couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, that's possible:

```
fun test (f, x) = f x
```

`test`now has the type `(('a -> 'b) * 'a) -> 'b`, which means that if you pass in a function that returns an int (like `inc`), the result will be an int and if you pass in a function that returns a list, the result will be a list.

As a sidenote: `double` could be more easily/idiomatically be defined as `fun double xs = map (fn x -> x*2) xs` or `val double = map (fn x -> x*2)`.